# Communication between Java ME application and C# application using bluetooth

Tags: c#, java-me, bluetooth, jsr82

I am C# developer which started working in Java lately, never done anything in Java ME. My next project requires to pass simple keypress from phone keyboard to C# application using bluetooth, there are some examples on sending/recieving files over bluetooh, but so little documentation how to pass messages between applications:

I stumbled on 32feet.NET library but provided samples are just poor, and bigger mystery for me is J2ME side of application.

if someone could provide any code samples or just explain some basic stuff and principals of bluetooth communication beetween phone and desktop applications:

- what bluetooth service is used for passing messages? Serial port?
- what type of data can is used for communication?
- how is connection kept alive?